# TreeView parent and leaf nodes of their root node

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have a tree-view with following Hierarchy

```
 Season 1
        Farm 1
              Field 1
              Field 2
                     Crop 1
                     Crop 2
        Farms 2  
              Field 1
              Field 2
                     Crop 1
                     Crop 2
```

And a GridView displaying Data agains treeview selected node value.I have use sqldatasource to show data in gridview with following Code and query

```
 Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
        If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Depth = 0 Then
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = ("SELECT * FROM V_FARMS where SSN_id='" & TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value & "'")

        ElseIf TreeView1.SelectedNode.Depth = 1 Then
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = ("SELECT * FROM V_FARMS where FRM_id='" & TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value & "'")

        ElseIf TreeView1.SelectedNode.Depth = 2 Then
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = ("SELECT * FROM V_FARMS where FLD_id='" & TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value & "'")

        ElseIf TreeView1.SelectedNode.Depth > 2 Then
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = ("SELECT * FROM V_FARMS where CRP_id='" & TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value & "'")
        End If
```

Now Problem is that when I select the Season 1 then it show the data against Season1 OK.
But When I select the Farm1 then it shows the all data against Farm 1 not all data against Season 1 of Farm 1 and also with Fields values are behaving same.How Can I show data of Each node against its above parant node and root node etc.

Comment: Not sure the problem is described correctly.  If you click on Farm 1 - Field 1, what is suppose to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: Actually When I Click Field 1 then it show data against both Farm 1 and Farm2 but i want to show the data of field under it corresponding farm and exactly same with all nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a suspicon that you're not using the .Depth property correctly. Try making the IDs of each node different values or possibly write the SQL statement into the tag of each node while you try things out.

Comment: Actually When I Click Field 1 then it show data against both Farm 1 and Farm2 but i want to show the data of field under it corresponding farm and exactly same with all nodes